# Regex remove specific tag and its content from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a given string:

```
"Hi there <ss type="laugh">:)</ss>"
```

When I'm using

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

It returns me

```
"Hi there :)"
```

How can i modify the Expression to remove all "ss" tags and everything between them?

Comment: something like `@"<ss(.|\n)*?ss>"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string contains a regular XML tag, thus, you can make use of `XElement`.

This code will just keep the text of the outer element (text outside tags):

```
var s = "Hi there <ss type=\"laugh\">:)</ss>";
var el = XElement.Parse(string.Format("<root1>{0}</root1>", s));
var result = string.Concat(el.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value)).Trim();
```

[image]

Just make sure to use `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

If you have other XML tags and you just want to remove `ss` tags:

```
var s = "<b>Hi</b> there <ss type=\"laugh\">:)</ss>";
var el = XElement.Parse(string.Format("<root1>{0}</root1>", s));
el.Descendants("ss").Remove();
var reader = el.CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent();
var result2 = reader.ReadInnerXml().Trim();
```

Result: [image]